# jQuery onChange event handler firing function twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the table http://jsfiddle.net/djochw6L/1/
The event is supposed to fire when I enter value in the item column

```
$(document).on('change', '.item', function() {
    var ite = $(this).closest('tr');
    getdetails(ite);
})//event

function getdetails(dat){
    var itemName = $(dat).find('.item').val();
    alert (itemName);    
};
```

The event handler works correct for the first row. But from the second row onwards it fires twice. Why is this?

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '.item', function(e) {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();` add this

Comment: Remove the item class from the new tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's firing twice is because your on change element fires for every class with the name item. If you look through your code you can see that on top of giving every table column the class item, you are also passing the item class to each row that is added. So the event fires twice, once for the row and once for the item column.

The code that's giving you the problem is

```
prot.attr("class", id + " item")
```

Try to fix your problem by not passing the item class to the table rows, instead of doing all kinds of hacky stuff to the event listener.

You could build your code to something along the lines of

```
prot.attr("class", "item-" + id)
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I didn't even notice the other item class.

Answer (score 0):

try adding return false:

```
$(document).on('change', '.item', function () {
    var ite = $(this).closest('tr');
    getdetails(ite);
    return false;
}) //event
```